# Are there any lossless camera image compression supported in ROS1 or ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2

I wanted to compress incoming raw images from the robot camera in ROS to store and upload efficiently. Raw images are huge and takes lot of space about 1 GB for 1 sec with 30fps. Need lossless compress algorithms that can be used while recording rosbag.

Answer (score 0):

The standard [ros image transport](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport) package supports PNG format. I should also note that if you’re using this to help with the size of bag files the standard [rosbag cli tools](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record) supports two types of bagfile compression, too.

Comment: Are there any other lossless algorithms supported in ros for image compression? As PNG takes a long time and doesn't have good compression ration.

Comment: @saumilsdk those are the only two supported natively by the image_transport package. I would still maybe think about bag file compression as a potential solution.

Comment: When i enable bz2 compression, my 1 CPU chokes to 100%. I don't want to use lz4 as it compression ration is not good. Is there a way to do GPU based compression or multiple CPU for compression?